# Changing text on email notification

Tags: php, email, wordpress

I am using the RSVP plugin from WordPress and have modified it so it can show which guests are invited to which event. When they go in and RSVP it sends an email which at the moment looks like this:

```
if((get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_ON_RSVP) == "Y") && (get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_EMAIL) != "")) {
    $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, rsvpStatus FROM ".ATTENDEES_TABLE." WHERE id= ".$attendeeID;
    $attendee = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if(count($attendee) > 0) {
        $body = "Hello, \r\n\r\n";

        $body .= stripslashes($attendee[0]->firstName)." ".stripslashes($attendee[0]->lastName).
                         " has submitted their RSVP and has RSVP'd with '".$attendee[0]->rsvpStatus."'.";

        wp_mail(get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_EMAIL), "New RSVP Submission", $body);
    }
}
```

In my database I have a field called rsvpEvent and I want it to get the data and show the person's RSVP to that event. I have tried adding this to it:

```
if((get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_ON_RSVP) == "Y") && (get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_EMAIL) != "")) {
    $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, rsvpStatus FROM ".ATTENDEES_TABLE." WHERE id= ".$attendeeID;
    $attendee = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if(count($attendee) > 0) {
        $body = "Hello, \r\n\r\n";

        $body .= stripslashes($attendee[0]->firstName)." ".stripslashes($attendee[0]->lastName).
                          "has been invited to '".$attendee[0]->rsvpEvent."'." "and has submitted their RSVP and has RSVP'd with '".$attendee[0]->rsvpStatus."'.";

        wp_mail(get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_EMAIL), "New RSVP Submission", $body);
    }
}
```

But it crashes my entire site, can anyone give me some hints or tips where I am going wrong?

Comment: Use a [decent IDE](https://netbeans.org/) and you'll see syntax errors before uploading faulty code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the **rsvpEvent** field from the database.

Try adding it to your SELECT query, as in:

```
if((get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_ON_RSVP) == "Y") && (get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_EMAIL) != "")) {
    $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, rsvpStatus, rsvpEvent FROM ".ATTENDEES_TABLE." WHERE id= ".$attendeeID;
    $attendee = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if(count($attendee) > 0) {
        $body = "Hello, \r\n\r\n";

        $body .= stripslashes($attendee[0]->firstName)." ".stripslashes($attendee[0]->lastName).
                          "has been invited to '".$attendee[0]->rsvpEvent."'." "and has submitted their RSVP and has RSVP'd with '".$attendee[0]->rsvpStatus."'.";

        wp_mail(get_option(OPTION_NOTIFY_EMAIL), "New RSVP Submission", $body);
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake I forgot to add that in (slap on head), Yes I have tried and uploaded and still comes up with server error :(